# Find element in selenium using xpath

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to find and click the element "Test 123" using Selenium Webdriver in C#. I've tried all the methods I can think of, but no good. I think the values are hidden before they are selected, but not sure. Any ideas, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46ydO.png)

Comment: Are you able to find the element, but not click?  Or, you can't find it at all?  How are you trying to find it?  Please show the code that you are using to do this.

Comment: Add the html code please. And link to the page

Answer (score 0):

Simple Xpath locator can do the trick:

```
public void ClickElementByXpath(string text) {
    IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(text(), '${text}')]");

    element.Click();
}

ClickElementByXpath("Test 123");
```